# libarb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, arbitrary-precision

I installed [arb](http://fredrikj.net/arb/#general-information) in Ubuntu using

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

and tried to run this code:

```
#include <arb.h>

int main()
{
    arb_t x;
    arb_init(x);
    arb_const_pi(x, 50 * 3.33);
    arb_printn(x, 50, 0); printf("\n");
    printf("Computed with arb-%s\n", arb_version);
    arb_clear(x);
}
```

with `-larb` libarary. But in terminal I got this error:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libarb.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

I searched and there is a libarb.so in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Try adding the path for libarb: -L/usr/local/lib -larb
But, are you sure that in /usr/local/lib there is a  libarb.so, or is like libarb.so.x.y.z ?

Comment: Yes. it's libarb.so.

Comment: How is this related to C++?

Comment: I made a C++ project. it seems to be C.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/673637/libarb-so-libflint-so-13-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-dire

Answer (score 3):

Check and verify these steps

1. check library is present, use below command

> find / -name "*libarb.so*"

2. compile your program with -L option, example below

> ```
>  gcc program.c -L <path to library> -larb
> ```

3. export Library path before running if required. example below

> ```
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:<path to library>
> ```

in most cases ( considering all access permissions are set properly ) the above steps should resolve linking problems.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ldconfig` command to add the library at the linker cache.

To do so, add the directory that your library is stored at the `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then execute `ldconfig` as root.